# How can I convert the C++11 code to C++98 without boost?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the function:

```
template<typename containerT>
void incElement(containerT c){
  for(auto i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) {
    for(auto j = (*i).begin(); j != (*i).end(); ++j) {
      ++(*j);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this work with C++98? I tried:

```
template<typename containerT, typename containerRowT, typename containerElementT>
void incElement(containerT<containerRowT<containerElementT> > c) {
  for(containerT<containerRowT<containerElementT> >::iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end; ++i) {
    for(containerRowT<containerElementT> >::iterator j = (*i).begin(); j != (*j).end(); ++j){
      ++(*j);
    }
  }
}
```

And it does not work and gives me error like:

```
test.cpp:4:17: error: ‘containerT’ is not a template
 void incElement(containerT<containerRowT<containerElementT> > c) {
                 ^
test.cpp:4:28: error: ‘containerRowT’ is not a template
 void incElement(containerT<containerRowT<containerElementT> > c) {
                            ^
test.cpp: In function ‘void incElement(containerT)’:
test.cpp:5:7: error: ‘containerT’ is not a template
```

etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to update your compiler and keep using the C++11 standard. You could use a recent GCC 4.8 and compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall`

Comment: What type ic container are you instantiating this with? Standard library containers define useful types you could use here, instead of multiple template parameters.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sadly, that is not always possible in the real world.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am working on an embedded board and it only comes with a g++ 4.6, and I need to use a library that is not fully compatible with C++11

Comment: I'm sure you could compile a [GCC 4.8.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) from its [source code](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/) for your embedded board, then recompile your library and your software.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Honestly no one will bother to do it... Even I did so, no one else here would spend a day or two trying to get all of GCC's dependencies and compile on a slow board like that. And my code won't be work on theirs

Comment: You should build GCC as a cross-compiler, hosted on your Linux laptop and targetting your slow board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the containers used follow normal `std` conventions, you can spell out the types explicitly:

```
template <typename containerT>
void incElement(containerT &c)  //assuming you want a reference here, otherwise you'll be mnodifying a local copy only
{
  typedef typename containerT::iterator TypeOfI;
  typedef typename containerT::value_type TypeOfStarI;
  typedef typename TypeOfStarI::iterator TypeOfJ;
  for (TypeOfI i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) {
    for (TypeOfJ j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j) {
      ++*j;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always replace `auto` by templates, because they follow the same type deduction rules:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void inner(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        ++*begin;
    }
}

template<typename Iterator>
void outer(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        inner(begin->begin(), begin->end());
    }
}

template<typename Container>
void incElement(Container& container)
{
    outer(container.begin(), container.end());
}
```

Note that I changed the signature of `incElement` to accept its argument by reference. Otherwise, a copy of the container would be modified, and the client would not be able to observe any changes.

Comment: +1 Certainly not the prettiest solution, but the only that provides functionally equivalent code.

Answer (score 4):

In the first version of your function, `containerT` is not a template. It is a class (and it can be an instantiation of a template, but that's irrelevant).

If `containerT` satisfies the standard Container concept then you would write:

```
for (typename containerT::iterator i ...) {
    for (typename containerT::value_type::iterator j ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well compiler tells you where the problem is. You are declaring `containerT` as a type, but you are using it as a template. So you can try to change `containerT` to template template argument (same for `containerRow`).

```
template<template<class> class containerT, template<class> class containerRowT, typename containerElementT>
void incElement(containerT<containerRowT<containerElementT> > c);
```

And what about this for STL containers:

```
template<typename containerT>
void incElement(containerT c){
  for(typename containerT::iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) {
    for(typename containerT::value_type::iterator j = (*i).begin(); j != (*i).end(); ++j) {
       ++(*j);
    }
  }
}
```