# Strategy of converting code from C++11 to C++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I have a project written in C++11. As C++11 is widely accepted, the project works well up to now, until I have to run it in a environment which not support C++11.

I have already used `std::shared_ptr`, `auto`, `std::intializer_list`, `nullptr` `enum class`,`chrono`, `std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4}` and many other C++11 technique everywhere in the project.

How can I move the big project in C++11 to C++98?

I apologize if it is a stupid problem, Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unlikely there's any tool for that. Lot's of manual work ahead of you.

Comment: Many of these libraries are provided by Boost for C++98.

Comment: The hard one is std::intializer_list because that one needs special compiler help so it probably can't be made to work easily.

Comment: Install a newer compiler, or if impossible, just refuse to deal with this environment. Why waste lots of effort on stuff destined to end up in the recycle bin? I understand this kind of solution is not going to work for everyone but that's one of several valid strategies.

Comment: By "have to run it", you mean have to develop it on  a c++98 compiler right ? Just to check if there is a confusion between compiler and runtime library. If you need to port it back for a c++98 good luck, can be tough. I would rather try to use a compiler back-port or compile inside a docker...

Comment: Let me expand a bit. C++98 is a language different from modern C++, just like C is a different language. A request to port your code to C++98 is like a request to port to C, perhaps there's less work, but qualitatively it's the same—a port to a different language. And then you will need to support that port separately. Do you have enough energy and resources for that?

Comment: I am write the code for high performance computing applications, I want project run on the Sunway TaihuLight Super Computer (Top3 computer in the world). However, it do not support C++11 yet, and the administrator said not sure when will the platform support C++11. In order to use the computer, I must to transfer the code to C++98. Seems I have to do the lots of manual work. Thanks for all advice~ @All

Comment: You probably don't have to *develop* on that computer. You just have to *run* your program on it. A binary doesn't care what compiler flags were used to produce it. Or, if you need to develop right on the platform, you might be able to download the sources of a modern C++ compiler, build it there, and install in your home directory.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. You are right. The problem is that computer is using cpu make by china, not x86 or arm. The compiler can only provided by computer adminstrator. So there is no modern C++ compiler on it. :(

Comment: From what little I can find about this architecture on the net, the sw compiler is based on gcc. People who developed it probably didn't contribute back to gcc tree, which is too bad.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes. the developer get from community but not give back. That's a shame. BTW, where you find the sw compiler information? could please you share me the link?

Comment: There is nothing except some filenames like sw5gcc and sw5g++ and sw5gfortran.

Answer (score 2):

Decide about each piece separately.

If that platform can run at least a subset of `boost`, you can probably just replace `std::chrono` and `std::shared_ptr`. You can also replace lambdas with `BOOST_LOCAL_FUNCTION`

Comment: I am decide going to have a look at boost now!

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar, but my challenge was co convert it from C++17 to C which was present on customer CentOS 7 (they used custom CentOS Image, and we were not allowed to install any new packages).

What I did was to throw out step by step all dependencies which used C++ elements and replace them with C variants. It took some time but it worked. Also looked after some other solution, but I was not able to find any.

You could always rewrite shared pointer, vector etc. in C.

Comment: You did do a great job, Sir. convert C++17 to C is much more harder :) You are my role model, I will start to do it now~

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you ask but when I want to run code to another computer without support C++11 I will create docker with C++11 inside this computer. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have never think about we can run the code in docker! you did expand my view~

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to try looking for C++ external libraries such as Boost and Qt, which could cover half of your requisites.

However some things are implementation-specific and upto you, such as the `auto` keyword, which you may choose to not use. (In fact if your using a proper debugger cum IDE, you'll get to check even complex data types in an instance)

Another alternative to that is replacing `auto` by templates, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063349/how-can-i-convert-the-c11-code-to-c98-without-boost). (without boost)

Similarly, stuff like macros and variadic templates shouldn't be hard to cover.